# Json object export to environment variable in python returning string without ""

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am creating a CDK stack using python.
Here I am exporting json object in to a linux environment as it is a clodebuild step.

```
f"export SHARED=\"{json.dumps(shared)}\""
```

The only reason to use `\"` is i was getting an error for spaces with in the json object.

When I am trying to import environment object and load it as json i am getting json object without `""`.

```
{
    mts:{
        account_id:11111,
        workbench:aaaaa,
        prefix:rad600-ars-sil,rad600-srr-sil-stage1,rad600-srr-sil-stage2
    },
    tsf:{
        account_id:22222,
        workbench:bbbbb,
        prefix:yyyy

    }
}
```

with this object below loads is not working and giving out an error which states `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

```
SHARED = json.loads(os.environ["SHARED"])
```

Am I missing something or is there a better way to send json object as environment variable?

Comment: You'll still have problems because JSON uses double quotes internally, and they'll match the quotes around the variable.

Comment: @Barmar yes, Thats why checking if there is a way around it.

Comment: You need to replace all quotes with `\"`, and all backslashes with ```\\ ```

Comment: Do you have to do this with a shell command, rather than something like `os.environ['SHARED'] = json.dumps(shared)`?

Comment: could you elabrate on using \\ ?

Comment: Yes, basically this is running on linux image during code build

Comment: _loads is not working_ Because that is not json.

Comment: @JohnGordon   yes, I have mentioned the reason in the question.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question.  If you _know_ it's not json, why are you trying to load it as json?

Comment: @JohnGordon  Question is: How do i pass the json object as environment variable and read it as json?
The above text discribcribs what i am doing to achive it and its not working for obvious reasons

Comment: Let me try another way.  How, exactly, did you get the object in that code sample?  Is it the output of some command or code?  If so, show us the exact command or code.

Comment: 1st script where i am exporting the json object. I am reading it from parameter store and it is part of bigger data. 2ns script where i am trying to import doesnt need the access data it only needs the "shared" values

Comment: possible workaround that avoids the problem entirely: encode the json string to base64. Then on the other end, decode the base64 string then load the json. Or use [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to properly quote the json string.

Comment: "1st script where i am exporting the json object" is much too vague.  Can you show us _exactly_ how it was produced?  What tool, _exactly_, produced that output?

Comment: @JohnGordon if your familiar with aws CDK, there a "config" object.  in place of exporting the whole config object i am only sending the config.shared.

Comment: No, I am not familiar with cdk.  But from my layman's perspective, it seems like you are expecting a cdk config object to be directly interpretable as json, when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

### Using base64

One foolproof way is to encode your json string as base64 first.

```py
import base64
json_bytestring = bytes(json.dumps(shared), 'utf-8')
b64_string = str(base64.b64encode(json_bytestring), 'utf-8')

command = f'export SHARED="{b64_string}"'
# ...
```

Then on the other end:

```py
shared_b64 = os.environ['SHARED']
shared_bytestring = base64.b64decode(shared_b64)
SHARED = json.loads(str(shared_bytestring, 'utf-8'))
```

This technique also works for arbitrary binary data.

### Using shlex.quote

Another way to do this would be to use [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to properly quote your json string for the shell command.

```py
command = f'export SHARED={shlex.quote(json.dumps(shared))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dump the JSON object to a string, with ASCII encoding and double quotes for keys
shared_str = json.dumps(shared, ensure_ascii=True)

# Set the environment variable
os.environ["SHARED"] = shared_str


# Load the environment variable and parse it as JSON
SHARED = json.loads(os.environ["SHARED"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is silly, but this worked.

I don't exactly know how it worked internally but replacing

```
f"export SHARED=\"{json.dumps(shared)}\""
```

with

```
f"export SHARED=\'{json.dumps(shared)}\'"
```

worked!

I feel while accessing the variable `os.environ["SHARED"]` it was nullifying `""` as the entire object had `""` within itself and by adding `'` this surrounded by object with `"` it was able to distinguish better.

Just a theory!!!

Comment: Though, this won't work if the JSON itself also contains literal `'` characters. `{"foo": "that's weird"}` You'll also find JSON containing escape sequences like `\"` and more will break similar approaches -- That's why tools like `shlex.quote` come in handy... it'll handle all those cases for you reliably, irrespective of the contents.